# How do I add application/json in the Header in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have a MongoDb & Node.js application.

I'm trying to push a new record to the database but I keep on getting the error message that I need to include "application/json" in the Header.

Below is the code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Person = require("./person");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/testdb")
const add = async () => {
    const person = await Person.create({
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 21
    })
    console.log(person)
}
add()

module.exports = app;
```

And below is the error message:

```
expected 'text/html; charset=utf-8' to include 'application/json'
```

How do I add "application/json" to the Header?

Comment: how are you calling this app?

Comment: @Bhumit070 I am not very experienced at this so I did not understand your question?

Comment: What do you do to cause this error?

Comment: @iamaprogrammer I meant like how are you calling this app function 
via postman or something else